# Mac MDM WiFi selection control remained after MDM profiles removed

Tags: network, wifi, monterey, mdm, configuration-profiles

Recently I've gained admin privilege and gotten rid of MDM profiles/limits.

However, after MDM profiles are removed I found that:

1. In Network -> Advanced -> Preferred Network,
   it still keeps erasing other WiFi locations, just keeping the 2~3 which are defined by the MDM.
2. While connecting to other WiFi locations, such as a hot spot, it would disconnect. Only the same 2~3 locations are allowed.)

Any clue how I can fix it? Where's the hidden configuration controlling this behavior?

Thanks!

--

MacBook Air M1
OS: MacOS Monterey

**The guide used to removed MDM profile**
https://graffino.com/til/UmkCdmEx7v-remove-a-non-removable-mdm-profile-from-macos-without-a-complete-wipe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue resolved by updating to MacOS Venturna, it's system preference allow user to control login items.

- Jamf Self Service
- JAMF Software
- StartupScript.sh

After above items turned off, my problem resolved.